# Implementing The Support Function in GJK

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection

Is there a way to pre-process the points of a convex polygon so that "furthest point given direction" queries are efficient? This is an important step in the GJK algorithm. The trivial solution is to, each time, scan the points of the polygon looking for the furthest one.

Comment: Sure, there is (e.g. by precomputing a table of distances for each point to every other point), but it's a significant trade-off between compute time and memory needed - if you only have a few points, it might be worth it, but the O(N^2) memory required can get out of control pretty quickly...

Comment: Thanks, how can the table be used to find furthest point given some direction?

Comment: Chances are, there won't be any point in a particular direction, unless you're on a regular grid of some sort. You'll likely need to check for points in a particular direction +/- some threshold. But you could easily pre-compute the direction vectors between every pair of points at the same time you pre-compute the distances...

Comment: The point does not have to be collinear with the direction vector. Given a set of points there is always at least one point that is furthest in that direction.

Comment: So, given a direction vector, you want the distance to the furthest line that is perpendicular to the direction vector and passes through one of the other points?

Comment: I think you got me wrong. The problem is: given a bunch of points on the plane and a vector, which one of the points is furthest in the direction at which the vector is pointing. Do you get the idea?

Answer (score 0):

http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/pubs/SIGGRAPH04_Ericson_GJK_notes.pdf says that in practice you can get the furthest vertex quickly in repeated calls by keeping track of the previous answer and working out the next answer by just moving from one vertex to an adjacent vertex to find a closer vertex. It also gives a pointer to a book "Real Time Collision Detection" by Ericson, published by Morgan Kaufman in 2005 (date from http://www.cosy.sbg.ac.at/~held/teaching/bakk_seminar/se_arbeiten_07-08/KollisionserkennungGJK.pdf)